# Android: Why can't I give an onClickListener to a VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have written these lines of code:

```
 mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    mVideoView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("LOG_TAG, click");
        }
    });
```

However, when I run my application, the click event is never called.

So I wonder, is it impossible to register an OnClickListener on a VideoView? And, if so, why is that the case?

Comment: mb need set clickable status : true ?  mVideoView.setClickable(true);

Answer (score 86):

use `VideoView.setOnTouchListener(..)` it works for VideoView

Answer (score 18):

Here's how I solved the pause/play of VideoViews using onTouch:

```
// Class variables
private boolean bVideoIsBeingTouched = false;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

vvVideo.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (!bVideoIsBeingTouched) {
        bVideoIsBeingTouched = true;
    if (vvVideo.isPlaying()) {
        vvVideo.pause();
    } else {
        vvVideo.resume();
    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            bVideoIsBeingTouched = false;
        }
        }, 100);
    }
    return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: For those where `resume()` does not work; here is solution [Stack](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11960730%2Fresume-playing-videoview-from-onresume&ei=JmbjUqmGK8P9rAe29IDYBA&usg=AFQjCNHWIPXnoKBCfV4ctFukFPDXYl303g&sig2=NJyXl7J9j8FA3AOBEmIXow&bvm=bv.59930103,d.bmk)

Comment: What is the purpose of 'bVideoIsBeingTouched' variable? As far as I can see you are only rewriting it but you don't use it.

Comment: using `bVideoIsBeingTouched` is horrible workaround, you should detect `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Answer (score 16):

I know this is old but I used this:

```
    mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Video 1 clicked, starting playback");

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to use this snippet but when I click, the activity closes and the app goes down.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same thing, and it is working for me now.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is and old question, but here is what I did:

Since setOnClickListener is not been triggered, I created my own class which extends VideoView

```
public class VideoViewCustom extends VideoView{
```

and Overrided the onTouchEvent

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN");
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

and now I can get the onClick event with the MotionEvent.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: In general, touch events for "click" should only be consumed on ACTION_UP, not ACTION_DOWN to allow the user to express intent to click. That's why other events like ACTION_CANCEL exist. The user begins to press, then moves their pointer outside of the bounds of the view.

Comment: Dallas is right, it should be  ACTION_UP instead of ACTION_DOWN

Comment: I just came across this problem and I agree that ACTION_UP is usually better practice but in this case the VideoView only seems to provide ACTION_DOWN!

Comment: I found the same, it only uses down

Answer (score 2):

This is probably long overdue, nonetheless of some help to those who may run into a similar problem. The way I got around this problem was by laying a transparent image view right on top of the video view, then listening to onClick events on the image view, and doing whatever it was I wanted to do with the video view afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but thought I'd chime in with an easy workaround. I can't answer *why* this doesn't work - seems like a big oversight in my opinion. But an easy workaround is to place your VideoView as the sole View inside a FrameLayout, and set an OnClickListener on the layout. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The VideoView is a wrapper containing MediaPlayer and SurfaceView. You can interact with through MediaController or writing your own SurfaceView and implement onClick events.

Comment: Interactions between a VideoView and a MediaController are quite limited. For example, during a tap action, VideoView will only check if MediaController is showing and show/hide it accordingly.
Although you can surely hack in these APIs, that is not what those APIs are expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can well use a button which is transparent on the video view if you want a specific part of the video on touch to do something.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue through cover layout.
I used the linearlayout.

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/video1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/video2"
                    android:layout_width="370dp"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:elevation = "0dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/video"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
```

and try it in source file.

```
video1.setOnClickListener {
                if(Video.isPlaying) {
                    Video.pause()
                }
                else {
                    Video.start()
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Gesture Overlay View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html)

You should be able to overlay this view on top of another view in order to get touch events.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: d'oh.  I was a newbie when I wrote this one :)

Answer (score -3):

It is possible I have did this with onSetClickListener. And Here's a code for your help:

```
mVideoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Here you put a condition for playing a video when you click on your video view.//
            if(my_video.isPressed())
            {   
                my_video.start();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Not able to run This Video!", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Man, this is exactly what the OP says he's doing! The point is that it does not work when video is playing.